# How to import products from Woocommerce to Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, woocommerce, ionic3, ionic4, woocommerce-rest-api

Hello I am trying to import products from Woocommerce website to an Ionic mobile app. I have created ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret to Woocommerce and I have set them to Ionic appp. In the beggining it worked, but now there is no product in my app. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: can you please add logs ?